# date format in AS3

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

I want my AS3 code to retrieve a specific date in MYSQL table.

I've got a format problem. 
When I write, in my AS3 code :

```
memberCombo.addItem( {label: "2015-06-23" } );
memberCombo.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, checkComplete);

function checkComplete(evt:Event):void {

    var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        myVariables.username = evt.target.value;
        var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.***.com/sql_date.php");

    myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    myRequest.data = myVariables;
    trace(myRequest.data);
```

the `trace(myRequest.data);` result `2015%2D06%2D23`
so it seems that it searching this `2015%2D06%2D23` in my SQL table (so it doesn't find it as the dates format in my table is `YY-M-D`).

Do you know how I can tell my AS3 code to look for the date in my SQL table in this format : `YY-M-D` ?

Thanks

---

**EDIT**

Here's what I did (but I made a mistake as it generate an error) :

```
    var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.****.com/sql_result.php");

myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    myRequest.data = myVariables;
    var myAS3Date;
    var myRequestString = "";
    myRequestString=dtAS3toMysql(myAS3Date);

function dtAS3toMysql( date:Date ):String {
    var s:String = date.fullYear + '-';

    // add the month
    if( date.month < 10 ) {
        s += '0' + ( date.month + 1 ) + '-';
    } else {
        s += ( date.month + 1 ) + '-';
    }

    // add the day
    if( date.date < 10 ) {
        s += '0' + date.date;
    } else {
        s += date.date;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: This is really needing php tag, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static function dtMysql2AS3( s:String ):Date {
        var a:Array = s.split( '-' );
        return new Date( a[0], a[1] - 1, a[2] );
    }


public static function dtAS3toMysql( date:Date ):String {
    var s:String = date.fullYear + '-';

    // add the month
    if( date.month < 10 ) {
        s += '0' + ( date.month + 1 ) + '-';
    } else {
        s += ( date.month + 1 ) + '-';
    }

    // add the day
    if( date.date < 10 ) {
        s += '0' + date.date;
    } else {
        s += date.date;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Hmm ok. Sorry but I don't see how my label can be concerted.. Could show me how I can use your convertMySQLDateToActionscript function to my label please ?

Comment: Hold on i will go the other way with it too

Comment: So, in my AS3 code, where do I call dtMysql2AS3 and dtAS3toMysql ? In my checkComplete function ?

Comment: create a string object, do the convert into it, and have that be your post data

Comment: Use dtAS3toMysql() in your case

Comment: Sorry for the question, but how I proceed to convert into the string ? I've created the string with `var myRequestString = "";` then I've got your `dtAS3toMysql()` function. How do I link both of them ?

Comment: myRequestString=dtAS3toMysql(myAS3Date); ... create an as3 date variable myAS3Date

Comment: I am typing on my phone so ya gotta figure it out

Comment: Like that ? :  `var myAS3Date;`
 `var myRequestString = "";`
 `myRequestString=dtAS3toMysql(myAS3Date);``function dtAS3toMysql( date:Date ):String {`.... (I'll edit my post for more visibility

Comment: var obj_name:Date = new Date();
This code stores in the "obj_name" variable the curent date and time. It uses the date and time set on the client computer

Comment: So now u have a Date(). Native AS3 datatype. My function gets a string for use with mysql